# GCP - gcloud List all accounts and the dataset it has access to

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud

I am currently implementing an audit process in our organization wherein we want to know all the dataset a particular service account has access to in Google BigQuery.

I did manage to look for a gcloud command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

But its just listing all the service account names and emails. If you could redirect me to a reference that would be really helpful

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this link will help us

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#dataset-acl

It seems to show all the access permissions for a given dataset using the command `bq show`.  Given this, we then see the roles and the members of that role for the dataset.  I fully understand that this is the inverse of what you want ... you want "given a user, which dataset's can he access" while this recipe gives "given a dataset, who can access it".  However, it feels like we could script the desired recipe.

Comment: @Kolban Thanks! I'll try to look in to the reference you gave see if I can figure anything out to solve my use case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the BigQuery CLI tool 'bq'. From BQ you can list all datasets in a project, and filter based on applied labels to those datasets using commands similar to:

```
bq ls
bq ls --filter labels.environment:prod
```

You can see the details of a dataset using

```
bq show datasetname
```

or

```
bq show --project_id 'my-project-1234' datasetname
```

Which will provide an output similar to:

```
  Last modified              ACLs              Labels 
----------------- --------------------------- --------   16 Oct 13:45:32   
Owners:
                      projectOwners,
                      FridayPush@org.com
                    Writers:
                      projectWriters
                    Readers:
                      secondaryUser@org.com,
                      projectReaders
```

Details about the [BQ CLI tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) are here. Here's my main suggestion, append the `--format=json` flag onto the end. Which will return all responses as json and allows easier bash scripting or use of tools like `jq` to process the response.